# "Pretending to be the bad-tasting butterfly can help the yummy one become a predator's lunch" -- is it correct to use "help" this way?

Tags: word-usage

I was reading [the news](https://student.societyforscience.org/article/how-moth-went-dark-side) and came across the following:

> A second study in the same issue of *Nature* focused on *Heliconius* butterflies [...] Nadeau is an evolutionary geneticist at the University of Sheffield in England. Her team was looking for genetic variants associated with the presence — or absence — of yellow bands on the wings. That coloring is important because that yellow band helps some yummy species of butterflies mimic vile-tasting ones. Pretending to be the bad-tasting butterfly **can help the yummy one become** a predator's lunch.

I wonder if it is correct to use the verb *help* that way. Logically, the sentence says that the coloring protects the butterflies from being eaten, but can it mean the opposite? Doesn't it actually say that the coloring can help a predator find the butterflies?

I think I can make the point clearer by replacing the *help* with its [definition](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/help_1), *make it easier*:

> Pretending to be the bad-tasting butterfly **makes it easier for the yummy one to become** a predator's lunch.

Comment: It seems like a mistake to me - 'Pretending to be the bad-tasting butterfly can help the yummy one **not** become a predator's lunch.' I would have written it '...makes the yummy one less likely to become a predator's lunch.'

Comment: Maybe it means "the (other) yummy-*looking* one".  Like the old joke, I don't have to outrun a bear, I just have to outrun you.

Comment: If you look disgusting, a predator will look for other prey.  That "helps" the other prey become dinner.  Such verbs are a feature of the "accessible" science article.

Comment: @TRomano I think you're on to something, but which butterfly is doing the pretending? It's awkward phrasing at best.

Comment: Species which pretend to look tasty would not last long. So the pretender is the one faking the "I'm poison" markings.

Comment: What @ColleenV said. I think the article wasn't proof-read properly (it should have been *can help the yummy one [**avoid becoming***...](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22avoid+becoming+a+predator%27s+lunch%22)). Per that Google Books link, this is practically a cliche.

Comment: @TRomano  '(The yummy one) pretending to be THE bad-tasting one can help THE yummy one become lunch' is just odd. The definite articles and "yummy one" just make the whole thing sort of vague and confusing to me. It seems to me that the author was too fixated on writing "yummy" and giggling and they didn't look over their "dumbed-down" version with a critical eye.

Comment: I'm not suggesting it was clear writing -- just trying to make some sense of it.  There is either a dropped **not**, as you suggested, or the writer is referring to another butterfly (the one to which the mimicker is being implicitly compared) and that other one is not only yummy but yummy-looking, or at least not advertising that it is toxic.

Comment: @TRomano I wasn't criticizing - just trying to explain why I asked "which butterfly is doing the pretending?"

Comment: I think that *avoid becoming* was the intended meaning as others have said. But *from becoming* is the more idiomatic way of saying this and then somehow people started dropping the preposition and then eventually the *-ing* too. I've seen this mistake before and I believe the author probably does not see there is confusion here and wrote it this way very much on purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As ColleenV and FumbleFingers state above, this must be a mistake. The intended meaning was certainly "can help the yummy one **not** become", or "can help the yummy one **avoid becoming**", or "can help the yummy one **by making it less likely to** become", or similar.